# Error : WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:12800/' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

Tags: javascript, python, html, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to make a Websocket from a javascript client that communicate with a python server.

My server is made like this :

```
connexions_asked, wlist, xlist = select.select([connexion_principal], [], [], 0.05)

for connexion in connexions_asked:
    connexion_with_client, infos_connexion = connexion.accept()
    clients_connected.append(connexion_avec_client)
    initCo = clients_connected[-1].recv(1000)
    initCo = initCo.decode()
    initCo = initCo.split("\n")
    secWebSocketKey = ""
    for line in initCo:
        if "Sec-WebSocket-Key" in line:
            secWebSocketKey = line
            break;
    secWebSocketKey = secWebSocketKey.split("Sec-WebSocket-Key: ")[1]
    magicStr = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"

    list_of_letters = list()
    for letter in secWebSocketKey:
        list_of_letters.append(letter)
    list_of_letters.pop(-1)
    for letter in magicStr:
        list_of_letters.append(letter)

    secWebSocketKey = "".join(list_of_letters)

    secWebSocketKey = secWebSocketKey.encode()
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1(secWebSocketKey).digest()
    sha1 = base64.b64encode(sha1)
    clients_connected[-1].send(b'HTTP/1.0 101 Switching Protocols\n')
    clients_connected[-1].send(b'Content-Type: text/html\n')
    clients_connected[-1].send(b'Connection: upgrade\n')
    clients_connected[-1].send(b'Upgrade: websocket\n')
    clients_connected[-1].send(b'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ')
    clients_connected[-1].send(sha1)
    clients_connected[-1].send(b'\n')
    clients_connected[-1].send(b'\n')
    clients_connected[-1].send(b"<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1> this is my server!</body></html>")
```

and my js client is like this :

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12800");

exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log("I'm connected");
};

exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
}

function sendMsg(str){
    exampleSocket.send(str);
}
```

When I call my server, everything seems to work, I can find "I'm connected" on my console but it raises a special error :

websocket.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:12800/' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

I have really no idea where it comes from. By searching on the internet, I found that it could come from a filtering of the web protocols but I don't know how to manipulate it.

Did anybody had this problem using WebSockets ?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I'm running into similar problem. Can you kindly advice.